# How can i host yii2 framework web app on azure

Tags: azure, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Anyone knows the best way to deploy yii2 framework web app on azure?. And is there any resource of how to connect database on azure.

Answer (score 2):

You can using App Service/Web App. Follow these steps:

1. Push your app to github/bitbucket or whatever (I am using github)
2. Open https://portal.azure.com and login into your account
3. Go to Create resource -> Web -> Web App
4. Fill up the form and click create button
5. After successfully created, open your created resource
6. Click Deployment Center -> Github -> Continue -> Kudu -> Continue
7. Choose your group, repository and branch -> Finish

Install Composer:

1. Click Console
2. Follow [this](https://getcomposer.org/download/) instruction
3. Execute `php composer.phar install -vv`
4. Execute `chmod +777 assets`
5. Don't forget to check the requirement here: `https://yourdomain.com/requirements.php`

Setup entry point:

1. Click Application Setting
2. Choose appropriate PHP version (7.X)
3. Go to **Virtual applications and directories** (At the bottom)
4. Change `site\wwwroot` to `site\wwwroot\web`
5. Save

Your Yii2 app should be running now.

To connect Azure Database just simply create the database on Azure, copy `server name` into `db.php`. If you want to test your app from localhost using Azure Database, don't forget to whitelist your public IP address on Database Firewall Setting

Answer (score 0):

You can check this blog, though it is referring using the Classic Portal you can follow similar steps in the New Portal.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2015/07/23/migrate-yii-framework-application-to-azure-web-app/